# A simple Linked List implementation in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to implement a simple linked list using c++. I am probably making a silly mistake somewhere.Through this i want to learn classes and pointers in C++.
For the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
public: 
    node* next;
    int data;

    node(int d);
    void append(int d);
}; 

node::node(int d)
{
    data = d;
    next = NULL;
}


void node::append(int d)
{
    node nw = node(d);
    if(next==NULL)
        next = &nw;
    else
    {
        node *n = next;
        while((*n).next!=NULL)
        {
            n = (*n).next;
        }
        (*n).next = &nw;
    }
}
```

I am getting 81 as the node next to 1.

```
int main()
{
    node n = node(1);
    n.append(3);
    n.append(2);
    n.append(81);
    n = *(n.next);
    cout<< n.data << '\n';
}
```

Please help me figure out where am i making mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might be other errors, but this is extremely dangerous: You are creating a local variable to represent the new node: `node nw = node(d);`, and then you make the last node in the list point to `nw`. However, since `nw` is a local variable, *it will cease to exist when the function returns*. So the `next` pointer of the last node now points to something that no longer exists. You need to use `new node(d)` (which returns a pointer to a `node`) in order to create an object that will continue to exist after the function has returned.

Answer (score 3):

You error is that you create an object on the stack, then store a pointer to it. The stack gets overwritten, your object gets overwritten, your pointer is invalid.

In your case the node that holds 3 is in the end overwritten by the node that holds 81.

Answer (score 1):

Might I also suggest that you make a LinkedList class separate from the Node class?  You can then move the append() method to that class and have it manage your nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
void node::append(int d) {
    node *nw = new node(d);
    node *last = this;

    while((*last).next!=NULL) 
        last = (*last).next;

    (*last).next = nw;
}
```

Yes, if your object are meant to stay around after function finishes you should create them on the heap (the **new** keyword), not on stack.

Comment: I had to use 
node * nw = (node*) operator new (sizeof(node));
new (nw) node(d);

Comment: @Nitin thats pretty weird. What compiler do you use?

Answer (score 0):

by using

```
node *nw=new node(d);
```

gives pointer to the same location every time which leads to the over-writing of the data.
so even by using new , the output is 81

find a way to create a new node which points to different memory address

my comments are blocked so i wrote this is answer
sorry for the inconvenience